# Wordcloud-Pillow issue

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-import, word-cloud

from wordcloud import WordCloud

### While importing WordCloud I get below issue.Can you help with this?

RuntimeWarning: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
Core version: 5.1.0
Pillow version: 4.2.1
  "The _imaging extension was built for Python with UCS2 support; "

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from wordcloud import WordCloud

:\Users\jhaas\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\wordcloud__init__.py in ()
----> 1 from .wordcloud import (WordCloud, STOPWORDS, random_color_func,
      2                         get_single_color_func)
      3 from .color_from_image import ImageColorGenerator
      4 
      5 **all** = ['WordCloud', 'STOPWORDS', 'random_color_func',

C:\Users\jhaas\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in ()
     17 from operator import itemgetter
     18 
---> 19 from PIL import Image
     20 from PIL import ImageColor
     21 from PIL import ImageDraw

C:\Users\jhaas\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in ()
     65                           "Pillow version: %s" %
     66                           (getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None),
---> 67                            PILLOW_VERSION))
     68 
     69 except ImportError as v:

ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
Core version: 5.1.0
Pillow version: 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

This is a Pillow problem, rather than a WordCloud problem. As it says, your Pillow installation has somehow become part 4.2.1, part 5.1.0. The simplest solution would be to reinstall Pillow.